# how can i fill more than one textview into listview's adapter

Tags: listview

> hi guys
>   i have a costume list view that it has three text view in each item row.
>   how can i fill this text view's content in adapter?
>   it doesn't let me to fill more than one text view.

```
JobShowList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.JobShowList);
    JobsArray=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.my_listview,R.id.JobsName, Jobs);
    JobShowList.setAdapter(JobsArray);
```

> thank you